# Networkx position nodes at graph's edges

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm very new to networkx graphs, so excuse me!
I was using this [code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_weighted_graph.html) to create a weighted network graph. Which works perfectly! But, I wanted to ask if there's a way to change the positions of all the nodes to be at the edges of the graph (with a circular layout) so it's clearer. Any ideas on how i could achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean with the edges? Like a circular layout? Why isn't this layout clear?

Comment: Yes, with a circular layout. It isn't clear because I have a lot of nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This layout seems fine to me for the shared example. In Networkx however, you have [several layouts](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/layout.html) which can be used to position the nodes in the graph. Based on your description, it looks like you might want a circular layout ([`nx.circular_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.circular_layout.html)) to have the nodes on the *edges* of the graph:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)  # positions for all nodes
# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=700)
# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=elarge, width=6)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    G, pos, edgelist=esmall, width=6, alpha=0.5, edge_color="b", style="dashed"
)
# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=20, font_family="sans-serif")

plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]